# Sharing folder within Linux machine to use it in Database Directory

Tags: linux, database, directory, share

I need to refresh the database with new dump files. But, unfortunately, that server machine doesn't have enough space. So, now trying to import same dump files, which is already present in the other machine (same network). Both machine has same OS running (Linux) with same version.

Now, I'm planning to share the source dump folder and create new directory in destination database, which will point network folder. But, I'm not sure how to share folder in Linux.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: To share directory only within two system, you two should be in seperate group. Ask you administrator to create a group and join the two systems you need to connect. Then set the permission to appropriate users.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to share the directory with NFS.   Here is a basic outline of the process.

On the server (where the files are):

```
yum -y install nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib      // your pkg manager may vary
vi /etc/exports
                                            // add a line like below
/directory/I/am/sharing    *(ro,sync)       // can replace * with an IP addr

service rpcbind start
service nfs start
chkconfig --levels 235 rpcbind on           // so they auto-start at boot
chkconfig --levels 235 nfs on

(open your firewall, if needed!)
```

On the client (who wants to see the files):

```
yum -y install nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib
mkdir -p /the/mount/point                   // you choose the name
mount name.of.your.server:/directory/I/am/sharing /the/mount/point

(to make the mount happen at boot, add this info in /etc/fstab):

name.of.your.server /directory/I/am/sharing /the/mount/point nfs ro
```

Notes:
* You may need `portmap` in place of rpcbind
*  `ro` means read-only, I assumed you wanted 1-way sharing.  You may want `rw`
* There are more detailed instructions all over the 'net -- google them

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try this.. I will get back to you, if I get any issue.:)